# How do I get a reference to a WCF service object from the code that creates it?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm modifying [the code in this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-events-and-callbacks) to build some basic subscribe push wcf client/server classes, and I've just hit a bit of a brick wall.

The server class in the tutorial is created using the following code:

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
        typeof(StringReverser),
        new Uri[]{
          new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
        }))
      {

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStringReverser),
          new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
          "PipeReverse");

        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service is available. " +
          "Press <ENTER> to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        host.Close();
      }
    }
  }
```

Which I assume publishes an instance of **StringReverser** my problem is I need a reference to that instance so I can call a method on it to push data back to the client.

In the tutorial the server just replies to the client using a callback method, instead I'm storing a reference to the client in a list of subscribers. When I need to push data back to the clients I need a reference to the Service object so I can actually utilize do the callback.

Is there a way to publish a Service using WCF that lets you have a reference to the service object? or can I get a reference to the service object from the **host** object?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: When you say "host" object, do you mean the service implementation?  And where exactly do you need the reference to it?

Comment: I need a reference to the service implementation from the code that publishes the service. so that I can periodically call a method on it to send data to any clients that have subscribed to data.

Comment: Basically the in the Main method above would be in the constructor of a dataPropogator class, the service implementation accepts subscribe calls over wcf, and when a method on the dataPropogator calss is called it sends data to all subscribers. I need a reference to the service object to do callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the singleton pattern in your StringReverser class and pass the instance of it to the ServiceHost constructor:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
  StringReverser.Instance,
  new Uri[]{new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")}
);
```

Comment: rather than passing a singleton can I just create an instance of StringReverser and pass that in.

Comment: This looks like the best solution.

Comment: I was able to use this method in C#, but I had to add the following attribute to my service class (in this example StringReverser):
    [ServiceBehavior(
        InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single        
        )]

Answer (score 3):

I agree that Julien's answer is the correct approach, but it is incomplete (at least for .NET 4.5).  After you pass in the instance of the service, you have to set the instance context mode for the `ServiceHost` to Single. If you don't do that, you'll get an error when the `ServiceHost` `Open()` method is called.

The way to set the context mode was not at all obvious. Here is a fragment from one of my programs, taken from a different SO answer:

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:15003/MockGateway");

using (var host = new ServiceHost(new MockGatewayService(), baseAddress))
{
    // Since we are passing an instance of the service into ServiceHost (rather 
    // than passing in the type) we have to set the context mode to single.
    var behavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
    behavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;

    // Continue to use the service here.  If you ever need to get a reference
    // to the service object you can do so with...
    MockGatewayService myService = host.SingletonInstance as MockGatewayService;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your servicecontract you can call

OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel());

in any method that is called after the service connects, and then pass it out of the service contract. I typically have a join method where I get a guid for the client and grab the callback there. This is harder than it seems. You either need a singleton/global variable to get it out (easy), or you need to make it so that WCF can use parameterized constructors (hard). For the latter, more correct way of doing it, you need to roll your own classes that implement IInstanceProvider and IEndPointBehavior and add your behavior to the endpoint you are interested in. This has the added benefit of allowing you to use different constructors with different endpoints without redefining your contract. There is unfortunately no typesafe way to do this as you will have to use reflection. Sorry I can't provide a sample, but everything I have is proprietary.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't that get me a reference to client not the server, I need a reference to the StringReverser I just created in program.cs not the client object that called the service.

Comment: Sorry, you can pass the stringreverser in as a constructor parameter. If you go the way of the accepted answer, you can only have a single instance of your class used by WCF. This will affect your concurrency model and performance.